# Variable methods in PHP?

Tags: php, abstract-class

I am writing a set of classes that handle simple file uploads with both ftp and ftps (not sftp) protocols.

Since the only difference between using ftp and ftps in PHP is the connect function, I thought that I could use a variable function in the form `$connection_function($host);`, where `$connection_function` has the either of the values `ftp_connect()` or `ftp_ssl_connect()`.

I made an abstract class that decides which to use. Simplifying for clarity, I wrote:

```
abstract class uploader {

  protected $connection_function;

  public function __construct($protocol) {
    if ( $protocol == "ftp" ) {
      $this->connection_function  = "ftp_connect";
    } elseif ( $protocol == "sftp" ) {
      $this->connection_function = "ftp_ssl_connect";
    }
  }

  public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {
    $conn = $this->connection_function($host);
  }
}

class ftp_uploader extends uploader {
  parent::__construct("ftp");
}

class ftps_uploader extends uploader {
  parent::__construct("ftps");
}
```

I get the error

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ftp_uploader::connection_function()`

Which obviously comes from 
      public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {
        $conn = $this->connection_function($host);
      }

So it occurs to me that I've written a variable *method* instead of a variable *function*, which is apparently not allowed (or treated as I expect it to be) in PHP.

Can I do what I want? The abstract class handles all of the ftp functions, and I would like to avoid duplicating code over two classes.

**Edit** Now that I've looked at it a bit, I see that I can just put the protocol decision in the conection method itself:

```
  public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {

    if ( $protocol == "ftp" ) {
      $conn = ftp_connect($host);
    } elseif ( $protocol == "sftp" ) {
      $cont = ftp_ssl_connect($host);
    }

  }
```

But still I wonder, is there a way to do my variable methods? As it is, I still have to duplicate my expection-throwing error handling and any other code I might want to put inside those if-blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the interpreter knows, you're trying to call that function, not use is as a variable:

```
public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {
  $conn = $this->connection_function($host);
}
```

Instead, try this:

```
public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {
  $func = $this->connection_function;
  $conn = $func($host);
}
```

And as [crashspeeder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880460/45531) mentions, you can also use `call_user_func()`, here's a slightly modified version of his answer:

```
public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {
  $conn = call_user_func_array($this->connection_function, func_get_args());
}
```

For this specific use case, that's likely the best solution, as you can easily pass on the arguments.

Comment: `$this->{$this->connection_function}($host);`is another (in this case quite ugly) way of doing the same

Comment: aw... I think curly braces are pretty!

Comment: @AD7six Was trying to find a way to use `{}`; however, he's calling a native function, not a function in the class.

Comment: @TimLytle yeah .. I didn't see/realize that.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to call the function you want.

```
public function upload($host, $file, ... ) {
    $conn = call_user_func($this->connection_function,$host, $param2, $param3);
}
```

You can also use [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) if you want to pass an array containing all your parameters.